# Переход по ссылке кликом по маркеру Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, google-maps-api

Вопрос, в принципе, ясен из названия. Есть карта Google Maps, есть нанесенные отметки. Как реализовать переход по ссылке для каждой отметки?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант добавить лисенер на клик и в колбек функции реализовать переход

```
marker.addListener('click', function {
//goto to link
});
```

Comment: marker is not defined говорит мне консоль. Возможно, я чего-то не понимаю)

Comment: @Riley маркеры то вы как наносили?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple